# How to decode the block data file in fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

This is about hyperledger fabric.

Here is the block file `/var/hyperledger/production/chains/mychannel/blockfile_000000` in orderer docker container.
So I have downloaded it to harddrive and How could I decode it?

Some say it's a **protobuf** file but I am not 100% sure about it.

Any suggestion would be helpful !

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes 
BlockFile can be decoded

1. First download the blockfile from docker
2. Use configtxgen to inspectblock and  decode the file in json

../bin/configtxgen -inspectBlock blockfile_00000 > blockfile.json

Answer (score 0):

You can easily read it using an editor. But you have to copy the folder into your local device first

```
docker cp orderer.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer/ ./orderer-backup
```

Comment: Hi Hoai, thanks for the advice！ Yes， it can be checked with any editor, but it's not fully decoded, so I was wondering if there is another way to check it in fully plain text?

Comment: With any SDK provided by fabric will solve this problem. Or there is a project working on this with progress: https://github.com/robinsonxie/fabric_blockdata